# Flutter form field validation null check operator used on null value

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, sorry for the long code. I think it would make more sense if I add the files that require it. Second, I keep on getting the the `Null check operator used on a null value` error even if (I think) the forms are populated. Can anyone point me to the right direction? I also just recently changed the dropdown into a formfield hoping that it would change but I still get the same error.

```
class SubjectForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Subject subject;
  final state = _SubjectFormState();

  SubjectForm({Key? key, required this.subject}): super(key:key);
  @override
  _SubjectFormState createState() => state;

  bool isValid() => state.validate();

} 

class _SubjectFormState extends State<SubjectForm>{

    static final List<String> _dropdownOptions = [
    "1",
    "1.25",
    "1.50",
    "1.75",
    "2.00",
    "2.25",
    "2.50",
    "2.75",
    "3.00",
    "5.00",
    ];

  final form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>
          [
              Expanded(child:TextFormField(
                initialValue: widget.subject.name,
                onSaved: (val) => widget.subject.name = val ?? '',
                validator: (String? val) {
                  if (val!.isEmpty){
                    return "Subjects cannot be empty";
                }
                return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Subject',
                ),
              )),

          Expanded(child:FormField(
            builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                value: widget.subject.grade,  
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  setState(() {
                      widget.subject.grade = value!;
                    });
                  },
                items:
                _dropdownOptions.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                (String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
                );
                },
                ).toList(),

              );
            },
            onSaved: ((String? value) {
              print('dropdown saved');
              }),
            ),
          ),
          
          Expanded(child:TextFormField(
            initialValue: widget.subject.units,
            onSaved: (val) => widget.subject.units = val ?? '',
            validator: (String? val) {
              if (val!.isEmpty){
                return "Units cannot be empty";
            }
            return null;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Units',
            ),
          )), 
        ]  
    ,)
); 
  }
  bool validate(){
  var valid = form.currentState!.validate();
  if(valid) form.currentState!.save();
  return valid;
}   
}
```

It always occurs whenever I press the compute button, and it leads me to the `isValid` method and subsequently the `validate` method as well both of which I made in the first bunch of code.

```
class MultiForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MultiFormState createState () => _MultiFormState();
}

class _MultiFormState extends State<MultiForm> {

  List <Subject> subjects = [];
  List <SubjectForm> forms = [];
  
  @override 

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  forms.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i<subjects.length; i++){
    forms.add(SubjectForm(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      subject: subjects[i]));
  }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text ('GWA Calculator'),
      ),
      body: 
        Column( 
          children: [
          ListView.builder (
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: subjects.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => SubjectForm (
            subject: subjects[i]),
          ),  
          
          Row (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: onAddForm, 
                child: Text('Add Subject')),

              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: computeGWA, 
                child: Text('Compute')),

          ],)

        ],),
    );
  }


  void onAddForm(){
    setState(() {
      subjects.add(Subject());
    });
    print(forms);
  }

  void computeGWA() {
    forms.forEach((form) => form.isValid());
  }
}
```

Comment: in the 'validation' part you are using val!.isEmpty, and that in itself is fine, you want to validate if it comes empty, but it still gives you an error, it happened to me recently, and I just changed it to something like this using your case. val! == null.
flutter tells us not to use that form to validate if it is null or not but in my case it worked that way.

Comment: @ChristianGodoy Hi i tried doing this but I still keep on getting the same error D: Ill keep this in mind in the future tho. Thank you!

Comment: now I managed to find your mistake! and what happens is that we cannot check if a variable is null or not if the variable has the '?' ahead, since there you are expressing that the variable is probably null or maybe not, who knows lol. so try removing the '?' in the validation. I hope that's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `From` widget and then pass formKey there.  like

```dart
  final form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: form,
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
```

And a safe method of checking validity is by checking null

```dart
 bool validate() {
    var valid = form.currentState?.validate();
    if (valid == true) {
      form.currentState!.save();
      return valid!;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

More about [forms/validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

Comment: Hi thanks, the errors were gone :D My problem now is whenever I click compute, I think it bypasses the null check. I tried removing the initialvalues from the text fields but nothing really happens. The message in the dropdown also does not show up even if there are values in it.

Comment: I cant find any Form widget on your widget. Did you wrap  with it

Comment: Yes I used the Form widget which I forgot tbh. I edited the post just now

Comment: It is missing  key on From widget